# inconsistent line ending behavior on firefox in windows

Tags: javascript, windows, http, firefox, newline

We are having a real bizarre issue, where when we do a post, line endings are `\r\n`, but when we pull the value using javascript, it just gets `\n`. This is causing issues, because for our system a create will be doing a normal form post, and a update will be pulling values from the form to build out an ajax request. Later, we are doing a string comparison on a given field, and are seeing this strange mix between `\r` being there or not being there.

IE handles this fine (ALWAYS `\r\n`), FF on windows will submit with `\r\n`, and in javascript will only report `\n`. What is REALLY FREAKIN STRANGE though is that on linux, both firefox and chrome will post with `\r\n`, and doing a `document.getElementById('text-area-id').value` will always show only `\n`.

Is this some dusty corner of the HTTP spec or something like that? Do the browsers implement this so that windows servers won't die? Is there any way around it, then sanitizing every field? What I would expect is both JS and HTTP POSTs to behave the same way, and use the system default on whatever system they happen to be on.

Answer (score 0):

`\r` is apparently an illegal character in the DOM, which is why you won't see it from script. Firefox converts platform linebreaks to `\n` when you set the textarea's value. On the other hand, when submitting a form thinks it needs to use the HTTP linebreak standard, which is apparently `\r\n`. So it converts them all before sending the form.